# WinForms - How to call the Window Documents Context Menu

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenustrip

On every windows app there is that context menu that you can access with CTRL+Space bar:

I believe this menu is called the "Window Control Menu", but I am not sure.

It has the following options:

> - Restore
> - Move
> - Size
> - Minimize
> - Maximize
> - Close   Alt+F4

Here is a pic:

[image]

How can I call this using win forms? My goal is to provide a keyboard shortcut to this menu by hitting alt+spacebar

Thanks.

Comment: I [think](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139835/how-can-i-open-a-windows-system-menu-by-code) this asnwers your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Send a message to your own window so that the system menu appears.

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, int lParam);

    private void callSysMenu()
    {
        int point = ((this.Location.Y << 16) | ((this.Location.X) & 0xffff));
        SendMessage(this.Handle, 0x313, IntPtr.Zero, point);
    }
```

Comment: And thanks for clarification on the nomenclature. So its known as the System Menu. Knowing what things are called is half the battle :)